# Instrumentation Test jacoco coverage report displays 0% coverage always

Tags: android, jacoco, android-instrumentation

I am facing a strange problem while running jacoco Instrumentation coverage.

SetUp -:
- In app/build.gradle file I have put "apply plugin: 'jacoco'"
- In debug variant under buildTypes I have put "testCoverageEnabled = true"

Run command -:
./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport

Result -:
- Coverage report is generated under /Users/user/AndroidInstrTests/app/build/reports/coverage/debug/index.html.
- But above index.html displays all coverage to be 0%.
- This should not happened as I have run same test on Google Notepad app, My app with content provider Tests(Which called insert method of content provider), I also ran one espresso instrumentation Test but got coverage as 0%.

[Jacoco Coverage report Instrumentation Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viBi9.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be because you are running coverage reports for your `test` packages instead of your `main` packages?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your point ?  .. All my tests are getting 100% passed.So it mean test execution happens properly. Also how come ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport this command will execute coverage for Tests ? Could you please tell where I am doing wrong ?